# tesseract training new fonts fail

Tags: tesseract

I was able install tesseract and train new fonts

I had followed all the steps exactly mentioned in http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine

And now i m testing the traineddata but i get the following error when i run the command

```
tesseract eng.digital.exp0.tif ./output.txt -l eng
```

gives me the error

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.03 with Leptonica
tessdata_manager.SeekToStart(TESSDATA_INTTEMP):Error:Assert failed:in file adaptmatch.cpp,    line 522
Abort trap: 6
```

Now, after this even if i'm trying to train new data, i get this error, 
i mean i'm unable to run the following command now

```
tesseract engg.digital.exp0.tif engg.digital.exp0.box nobatch box.train.stderr
```

I was able to resolve this error by uninstalling and installing tesseract again. 
Could you guys help me, if there is an easier way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have fixed the 2nd time run fail. Basically i was training another font in english and i replaced eng.traineddata in original tessdata folder.. Hence it was failing. I replaced the original eng.traineddata and i can retrain now.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error because names on .box and .tif didnt match. After making sure each pair have language.fontName.countNumber.tif and language.fontName.countNumber.box it stopped crashing at this error.