# Tesseract Segmentation fault for custom font (lang)

Tags: tesseract

(*I'm new with Tesseract, could miss understand lot of things*).

I followed [this article](http://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine/) to train Tesseract for a specific font.

Everything worked as expected, so I have in my `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/` a new file `eve.traineddata` (the only file I copied because the article didn't asked for more).

But now, when I run:

```
/usr/local/bin/tesseract -l eve image.png textfile
```

I got:

```
mgr->GetComponent(TESSDATA_INTTEMP, &fp):Error:Assert failed:in file adaptmatch.cpp, line 537
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This only append with `-l eve` (obviously).
I didn't found any explanation on the internet (even if it's seems to be a usual issue).

I would like to at least understand what is going wrong and if possible learn how to fix it.

Did I done something wrong when computing `eve.traineddata` or can it be another thing?

---

*This question is not the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811703/tesseract-training-new-fonts-fail), we have the same error, but I don't want to bypass it and didn't overridden my `eng.traineddata` file.*

---

*I can link traineddata file if needed, but I'm not sure it's helpful.*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_language <-- Is this the language? Did you also follow e.g. this page to add a new language? https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract2

Comment: @sneep no, "eve" is the name of a video game and i'm trying to train for "evesans" font. I didn't followed the page you linked but the article I linked in my question - I'm trying to start from scratch with the official doc - I would keep you informed

Comment: I haven't done this before and cannot be 100%, but I think it's looking for language data for a language called `eve`. This doesn't exist, so maybe try to either call your file `eng.traineddata` or copy the other `eng.` data files and name them `eve.*`

Comment: @sneep the error is not the file `traineddata` is not found, but it looks like it's not well formated or something. The error message for this is `Failed loading language 'langname'`. Here it load my `eve.traineddata` but fails

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using tesseract 3 traineddata with tessereact 4-alpha lstm?

Comment: @DmitriiZ.Yes. But yea, I thought to that too, I tried the whole thing in v4 first, then in v3 from scratch, not the exact same error but still segfault. I hope to have time to make a Vagrantfile for both tomorrow. I would like to understand what is going on..

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error because my .box and .tif files didn't have matching names. After making sure I have pairs of lang.fontName.countNumber.tif and lang.fontName.countNumber.box it started to work. Hope this helps